# Convert binary data to web-safe text and back - Python

Tags: python, file, binary, ascii, utf

I want to convert a binary file (such as a jpg, mp3, etc) to web-safe text and then back into binary data. I've researched a few modules and I think I'm really close but I keep getting data corruption.

After looking at the documentation for [binascii](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/binascii.html?highlight=b2a#binascii.b2a%5Fqp) I came up with this:

```
from binascii import *
raw_bytes = open('test.jpg','rb').read()
text = b2a_qp(raw_bytes,quotetabs=True,header=False)
bytesback = a2b_qp(text,header=False)
f = open('converted.jpg','wb')
f.write(bytesback)
f.close()
```

When I try to open the `converted.jpg` I get data corruption :-/

I also tried using `b2a_base64` with 57-long blocks of binary data. I took each block, converted to a string, concatenated them all together, and then converted back in `a2b_base64` and got corruption again.

Can anyone help? I'm not super knowledgeable on all the intricacies of bytes and file formats. I'm using Python on Windows if that makes a difference with the `\r\n` stuff

Comment: base64 always seemed to work for me on this. Maybe serializing/pickling the data first?

Comment: You must have a custom-built bassackwards version of Windows -- the standard issue has `\r\n` stuff.

Comment: Don't put answer in the question (I've moved your answer from the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868572/convert-binary-data-to-web-safe-text-and-back-python/7871688#7871688)). To mark the question "*Solved*" just accept the best of the answers including your own answers.

Answer (score 1):

You should use base64 encoding instead of quoted printable. Use `b2a_base64()` and `a2b_base64()`.

Quoted printable is much bigger for binary data like pictures. In this encoding each binary (non alphanumeric character) code is changed into `=HEX`. It can be used for texts that consist mainly of alphanumeric like email subjects.

Base64 is much better for mainly binary data. It takes 6 bites of first byte, then last 2 bits of 1st byte and 4 bites from 2nd byte. etc. It can be recognized by `=` padding at the end of the encoded text (sometimes other character is used).

As an example I took .jpeg of 271 700 bytes. In qp it is 627 857 b while in base64 it is 362 269 bytes. Size of qp is dependent of data type: text which is letters only do not change. Size of base64 is `orig_size * 8 / 6`.

Comment: Yep that worked, thanks for the help. The reason why it wasn't working earlier is that I was using `raw_bytes[0:56]` instead of `[0:57]`. I also was appending strings with '+=' instead of joining a string list, but I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: FTR: It takes 6, 2+4, 4+2, 6 bits. With 7 bits, it would be Base128.

Answer (score 1):

Your documentation reference is for Python 3.0.1. There is no good reason using Python 3.0. You should be using 3.2 or 2.7. What exactly are you using?

Suggestion: (1) change `bytes` to `raw_bytes` to avoid confusion with the `bytes` built-in (2) check for `raw_bytes` == `bytes_back` in your test script (3) while your test should work with quoted-printable, it is very inefficient for binary data; use base64 instead.

Update: Base64 encoding produces 4 output bytes for every 3 input bytes. Your base64 code doesn't work with 56-byte chunks because 56 is not an integral multiple of 3; each chunk is padded out to a multiple of 3. Then you join the chunks and attempt to decode, which is guaranteed not to work.

Your chunking loop would be much better written as:

```
output_string = ''.join(
    b2a_base64(raw_bytes[i:i+57]) for i in xrange(0, xrange(len(raw_bytes), 57)
    )
```

In any case, chunking is rather slow and pointless; just do `b2a_base64(raw_bytes)`

Comment: I'm using 2.7, sorry for omitting that. I checked for `raw_bytes == bytes_back` and I get `False` with the above script, so I'm not sure if it's an issue with the way Python compares byte strings or if I'm not specifying the right parameters when calling the function.

Comment: Turns out it works with base64 if I divide it up into chunks of [0:57] instead of [0:56]; I'll write it up in the question now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks quite complicated. Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from binascii import *
raw_bytes = open('28.jpg','rb').read()
i = 0
str_one = b2a_base64(raw_bytes) # 1
str_list = b2a_base64(raw_bytes).split("\n") #2

bytesBackAll = a2b_base64(''.join(str_list)) #2
print bytesBackAll == raw_bytes #True #2

bytesBackAll = a2b_base64(str_one) #1
print bytesBackAll == raw_bytes #True #1
```

Lines tagged with `#1` and `#2` represent alternatives to each other. `#1` seems most straightforward to me - just make it one string, process it and convert it back.

Answer (score -2):

@PMC's answer copied from the question:

Here's what works:

```
from binascii import *
raw_bytes = open('28.jpg','rb').read()
str_list = []
i = 0
while i < len(raw_bytes):
    byteSegment = raw_bytes[i:i+57]
    str_list.append(b2a_base64(byteSegment))
    i += 57
bytesBackAll = a2b_base64(''.join(str_list))
print bytesBackAll == raw_bytes #True
```

Thanks for the help guys. I'm not sure why this would fail with [0:56] instead of [0:57] but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader :P

Comment: This does "work" but it's an extreme example of code bloat -- see my updated answer.

Comment: @John Machin: if it is unclear: it is a \@PMC's answer. Direct your comment to him.

Comment: The comment was directed at the world in general.